# How to draw this picture in Context?

Tags: tables, formatting, context

I want to typeset a figure that expresses how some quantity consists of other quantities, and graphically depict that in a table like form. 
I have currently done this using a simple table format, and used the vertical line to express that the values in the next column belong to the value in the previous column. But I want to replace that vertical line with a vertical left brace.

The current code looks like this:

```
\starttable[s0|cp(.2\textwidth)|cp(.2\textwidth)|cp(.2\textwidth)|cp(.25\textwidth)|]
\NC \NC \VL Variabel\\ kapitaal\\ 10 \VL Arbeidsloon v/d\\
productie-arbeiders\\ 10 \NC \AR
\NC \NC \VL  \NC \NC \AR
\NC \NC \VL  \NC \NC \AR
\NC \VL Nationaal\\ inkomen\\ 30 \VL \VL Winst van de\\ industriële
kapitalist\\ 10 \NC \AR
\NC \VL \VL  \VL \NC \AR
\NC \VL \VL \VL Commerciële\\ winst\\ 3 \NC \AR
\NC Totaal\\ maatschappelijk\\ product\\ 90 \VL \VL Meerwaarde\\ 20 \VL 
Rente\\ 2 \NC \AR
\NC \VL \VL  \VL Grondrente\\ 5 \NC \AR
\NC \VL \NC  \NC  \NC \AR
\NC \VL Vervanging \\ v/h verbruikte \\ constante\\ kapitaal\\ 60 \NC \NC 
\NC \AR
\stoptable
```

In a simpler form, I could have used mathcases, where the vertical left brace expands to the needed vertical size, but I could not get it to work in a nested form. Is there a work around?

Other alternative would be to replace the vertical lines in the table with an extra column for each vertical line, and place the left brace symbol there, properly vertically lowered and stretched vertically. Is there a way to do that?

The picture (taking symbols for the labels) would look something like this:
[image: picture]

Comment: Can you post an image that show what result you are after,

Comment: A similar question was asked on the mailing list some years ago; Wolfgang Schuster provided two possible solutions which may be interesting for you: http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.context/58936

Comment: @Thomas You can post them here.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a graphical package such as metapost or tikz to draw such diagram. Tikz probably already has a nice interface for this. Here is a barebones examples of how to draw such tables in metapost.

```
\useMPlibrary[fen] % To get BasicBraceSymbol 

\defineframed
    [quantity]
    [
      align=middle,
      width=0.25\textwidth,
      frame=off,
    ]

\startMPinclusions
  input boxes;
\stopMPinclusions

\starttext
\startMPcode
  boxit.totaal("\quantity{Totaal\\ maatschappelijk\\ product\\ 90}");
  boxit.nationaal("\quantity{Nationaal \\ inkomen \\ 30}");
  boxit.kapitaal("\quantity{Vervanging \\ v/h verbruikte \\ constante\\ kapitaal\\ 60}");

  newnumeric ux, uy;

  totaal.c = origin;

  xpart (nationaal.w - totaal.e) = EmWidth;
  xpart nationaal.c = xpart kapitaal.c;
  ypart (nationaal.s - totaal.n) = ypart (totaal.s - kapitaal.n) = 3LineHeight;

  drawunboxed(totaal, nationaal, kapitaal);

  boxit.brace(
    image(fill BasicBraceSymbol(0) ysized (ypart (nationaal.n - kapitaal.s))));

  brace.ne = nationaal.nw;
  brace.dx = brace.dy=0;

  drawunboxed(brace);

\stopMPcode
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

You can probably wrap this around a Metapost marco to draw a tree-like structure.

Comment: Thanks. That is the kind of result I am after. I hope I can figure out how to extend this for the other fields.

Comment: And in addition to this question (more for my understanding of how Context handles this), why a more straighforward solution like 1) Placing the brace-symbol in a box and stretch that box to the desired vertical size, and placing that in a seperate column inbetween lowered to the desired row or 2) Using the already existing mathcase construction in a nested way (placinc one mathcase construction into another), not work?

Answer (score 1):

The solution I now found (using the code provided by Wolfgang Schuster) looks like this, which is almost ok.

code:

```
\startuseMPgraphic{accolade}
z1  = (-233,0) ;
z2  = (-220,22) ;
z3  = (-155,211) ;
z4  = (-200,690) ;
z5  = (-142,1033) ;
z6  = (-97,1106) ;
z7  = (-71,1125) ;
z8  = (-61,1104) ;
z9  = (-80,1077) ;
z10 = (-108,1002) ;
z11 = (-129,666) ;
z12 = (-117,207) ;
z13 = (-197,19) ;
z14 = (-208,0) ;
z15 = (-197,-19) ;
z16 = (-117,-207) ;
z17 = (-129,-666) ;
z18 = (-108,-1026) ;
z19 = (-80,-1077) ;
z20 = (-61,-1104) ;
z21 = (-71,-1125) ;
z22 = (-97,-1106) ;
z23 = (-143,-1031) ;
z24 = (-199,-673) ;
z25 = (-155,-211) ;
z26 = (-220,-22) ;
fill z1 for i=2 upto 14: .. z[i] endfor & z14 for j=15 upto 26: .. z[j] 
endfor .. z1 & cycle ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\defineoverlay[rlbrace] [\rightaligned{\scale[height=\overlayheight]{\useMPgraphic{accolade}}}]

\starttext

\setupTABLE[frame=off,offset=1ex]
\setupTABLE[row][each][align={middle,lohi}]
\setupTABLE[c][1][width=.31\textwidth]
\setupTABLE[c][2][width=.21\textwidth]
\setupTABLE[c][3][width=.21\textwidth]
\setupTABLE[c][4][width=.27\textwidth]
\bTABLE
\bTR
\bTD[nr=6,background=rlbrace]  Totaal\\ maatschappelijk\\ product\\ 90
\eTD
\bTD[nr=5,background=rlbrace] Nationaal\\ inkomen\\ 30 
\eTD
\bTD[background=rlbrace] Variabel\\ kapitaal\\ 10
\eTD
\bTD Arbeidsloon v/d\\ productie-arbeiders\\ 10
\eTD 
\eTR
\bTR
\bTD[nr=4,background=rlbrace] Meerwaarde\\ 20
\eTD
\bTD Winst van de\\ industriële kapitalist\\ 10 
\eTD 
\eTR
\bTR
\bTD Commerciële\\ winst\\ 3
\eTD 
\eTR
\bTR
\bTD Rente\\ 2 
\eTD 
\eTR
\bTR
\bTD Grondrente\\ 5
\eTD 
\eTR
\bTR
\bTD Vervanging \\ v/h verbruikte \\ constante\\ kapitaal\\ 60 
\eTD
\bTD[nc=2]
\eTD
\eTR
\eTABLE


\stoptext
```

picture:
[image]

The only thing I want is that the braces do not fill the whole height, but some percentage of it (say: 90%), while keeping the table dimensions the same (not affecting the height of the rows), so that the braces do not touch each other when one is above another.

How can I do that?

A) changing the code for the overlay so that some vertical space is filled in the top and bottom, and have the brace symbol shrunk a little (for example: 5% on top, 90% for the brace symbol and 5% in the bottom, so the height stays the same, only the brace symbol looks little smaller)?

or

B) changing something to the table layout having the effect that there is a little space between the rows, or each row has some vertical space in the top and the bottom (but this would probably also effect the height of the background layout, which then solves nothing)?

C) 
And a third option (but probably ugly hack) is to add extra blank row where necessary.

Comment: Found a solution now, after trying different alternatives. I first tried to set the height of the overlay to 90% of the overlayheight, but the term "height=.9\overlayheight" wasn't understood by Context (why not?). But adding another scale with scale=900 does the trick: \defineoverlay[rlbrace][\rightaligned{\scale[scale=900]{\scale[height=\overlayheight]{\myaccolade}}}]